# If $45=(6-a)(6-b)(6-c)(6-d)(6-e)$ then find $a+b+c+d=?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider $(6-a)(6-b)(6-c)(6-d)(6-e)$ are five distinct factors of $45$. What is $a+b+c+d$

The problem I am facing is that I am supposing
$b = 1$,
$c = 5$,
$d = 3$
The problem is coming in supposing the value of $a$ and $e$. So can you tell whether I am on the right path or not.

Comment: How can $6-a$ and $6-a$ be distinct? Do you mean $6-e$ perhaps?

Comment: We can suppose $(6-a)^{2}$ as one factor . Yeah it could be $6-e$ too.

Comment: So which is it?

Comment: $6-e$ it is ....

Comment: The problem is poorly stated or you've omitted something.

Comment: Or the problem requires to write the sum considering all the possible combinations of the factors of 45 (-45,-15,-9,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,9,15,45). Smin=-74.Smax=+74.

Comment: i think a possible duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any factor of $45$ can be written as followed : $$\pm 3^{r_i}5^{s_i}$$ where $0\leq r_i \leq 2$ and $0\leq s_i\leq 1$

So since they must be all different, we can write:
$$(6-a)=3$$
$$(6-b)=5$$
$$(6-c)=-3$$
$$(6-d)=1$$
$$(6-e)=-1$$
From here it is easy to deduct that
$$a=3$$
$$b=1$$
$$c=9$$
$$d=5$$
$$e=7$$

It follows $$a+b+c+d=3+1+9+5=18$$
Clearly, the solution is not unique.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* $45=1\cdot (-1)\cdot 3\cdot (-3)\cdot 5$

Answer (score 2):

You can suppose a as "-3" and b as "-9" 
So this will solve your problem 
(6-(-3))=9
(6-(-9))=15
Both 9 and 15 are factors of 45

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $45=3\times3\times5$. Now it is given to us that there are 5 factors and all must be distinct. So let's try to arrange it so that condition is satisfied.

$45=3\times3\times5\times1\times-1$. Oops, $3=3$ (Not distinct)

This false example made me realise that I have only three factors and I have to make $5$ from them. Then I remembered The dialogue of the movie *Stand And Deliver* that **Negative times Negative Equals Positive**.

So, $45=3\times3\times5=1\times3\times3\times5\times1=1\times3\times-3\times5\times-1$.

Is this enough.....??